# How to upload the data from excel sheet to database using asp .net mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Hello friends This is my biometric generated attendance sheet.

I want to upload this sheet value into database.

My table field names are
EmpName
empId,
Status,
Intime,
Outtime,Working hour

[image]

---

D: Days, S: Status, I: InTime, O: OutTime, W:Working Hours 
A: Absent, P: Present, Ho: Holidays,  L: Leaves, wo: Weekily Off
TDay: Total Days Present, HD:HalfDay , o: Overtime Hours
![enter image description here][2]

How can I upload the data into database using asp.net mvc 4using C#

Comment: A very broad question. What have you tried? What problems did you encounter?

Comment: Actually I want to upload the excel to the databse @PHeiberg